# django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py full path please for ubuntu

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu

Need full path for django.db.backends folder.

I already searched for django folder in usr/lib, usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
but unable to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:
`$ locate django/db/backends`.
This will give you all the possible paths where **django/db/backends** exists.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe one more trick - python modules has a **__file__** attribute:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> models.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/__init__.pyc'
```

And this is for *backends* module in python3:

```
>>> from django.db import backends
>>> backends.__file__
'/home/myusername/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py'
```

It is pretty useful - and works just from python console.

Good luck :)